# What is the average salary of the employees who have the highest commission

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, analytic-functions

I am trying to do this question and need some hints, I want to do it with the analytic function in oracle sql.
What is the average salary of the employees who have the highest commission

Comment: You might want to take a look a aggregation function?

Comment: Please share more information on your table structure and what are you looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is hard to give you an proper answer without any details, but I will try.
You can do something like this:

```
SELECT
  T1.EMPLOYEE_NAME AS NAME,
  T1.SALARY AS SALARY,
  AVG(CASE WHEN T1.COMMISSION >=(
       SELECT MAX(COMMISSION) FROM EMPLOYEETABLE)
           THEN SALARY
           ELSE 0
           END) AS AVG_SALARY
FROM EMPLOYEETABLE T1
GROUP BY T1.EMPLOYYEE_NAME, T1.SALARY
ORDER BY T1.SALARY DESC
```

Maybe you can give further details on your table structure and data model.
Bye.